# Strange exception when calling code in a web service vs a windows exe

Tags: web-services, com, serialization, interop

I'm interoping with some com objects in a web service using code shared with a windows app.  The window apps has no problems interoping with the com objects but the web service throws this exception

```
'Type 'MapShots.FODDs.ilfFOD.fodDescriptions' in Assembly 'ilfFOD, Version=1.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.'
```

I'm not trying to return any of the objects from the web method, just trying to do some work on the server to return to the client.  Does anyone have any ideas what could be happening, search online hasn't returned much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have any idea how I could help you without at least seeing the complete exception, with all InnerException and stack traces. Better yet, could you post some code and not keep me guessing?

Comment: BTW, make sure the COM objects are thread safe and tested to run in a multithreaded environment. Many COM objects were built to run from a Windows desktop application and will not work properly when called from a web application or web service.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the code you could try marking fodDescriptions as Serializable.

Check that all the objects used as input to and output from the web service, including sub objects are marked as serializable.